# I have installed chefdk In my workstation and created a directory called chef-repo

Tags: chefdk

I have a question here.

I have installed chefdk In my workstation and created a directory called chef-repo. Now my question is how can I test the cookbook? And the bin folder is having all the binaries related to chefdk location /opt/chefdk/ From where is can upload the cookbook

Answer (score 0):

if you have acess to your chef server running then I would refer to this url on how to upload your cookbook with knife
https://learn.chef.io/modules/manage-a-node-chef-server/rhel/hosted/upload-a-cookbook#/

If you want to test you cookbook locally on your workstation you will have to run the chef in local-mode.

```
chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[<<cookbook-name>>::<<recipe-name>>]'
```

Comment: My question is how I can test a cookbook from chefdk locally as my chef server is running on the other node. Do I need to bootstrap the workstation?